# Global name "fc' not defined?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, nameerror

First, I'm trying to call a function from a module (final_functions) I created in a separate script. However I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 325, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__   File "C:\EsriPress\Python\Data\Final\Test.py", line 8, in <module>
    check = final_functions.FieldExists(fcname, fieldname)   File "C:\EsriPress\Python\Data\Final\final_functions.py", line 6, in FieldExists
    namelist = [] NameError: global name 'fc' is not defined
```

Here's the main script:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/EsriPress/Python/Data/Final/Scratch.gdb"
import final_functions
fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('Fire*')
for fc in fclist:
    fc = fcname
    fieldname = "SFCount"
    check = final_functions.FieldExists(fcname, fieldname)
    print check
```

Here is the module (final_functions.py) I'm importing:

```
def FieldExists(fcname, fieldname):
    namelist = []
    fields = arcpy.ListFields(fcname)
    for field in fields:
        namelist.append(field.name)

    if fieldname in namelist:
        return "Field: SFCount already present in Feature Class:     {0}".format(fcname)
    else:
        arcpy.AddField_management(fcname, fieldname, "TEXT")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('Fire*')
    for fc in fclist:
        fieldname = "SFCount"
        fcname = fc
        checkfields = FieldExists(fc, fieldname)
        print checkfields
```

When I run final_functions on its own, it works great. I'm only given the error when trying to call it in the main script.

And if you're wondering, I'm just checking a list of feature classes for the existence of a field, and adding a new field if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason it works inside your module is that you are passing each feature class (*fc*) into your function.

If you look carefully you can see that the line:

```
fcname = fc
```

is redundant. Here you are essentially reassigning the feature class to the variable *fcname* and then not using it i.e.

```
checkfields = FieldExists(fc, fieldname) # you are still passing fc to your function
```

---

As for your main script, you are looping through each feature class as *fc* but then saying:

```
fc = fcname
```

however *fcname* is not defined. So you could create the variable *fcname* by assigning it to your feature class inside your loop (as you have done inside your module), and ensure you then pass *fcname* into your function:

```
for fc in fclist:
    fcname = fc # create new variable to store feature class (unnecessary)
    fieldname = "SFCount"
    check = final_functions.FieldExists(fcname, fieldname) # new variable passed to function
    print check
```

but this is unnecessary as you already have a variable that is storing your feature class - *fc*. So, just remove this reassignment and pass *fc* into your function. Therefore I would change your main script to:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/EsriPress/Python/Data/Final/Scratch.gdb"
import final_functions
fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('Fire*')
for fc in fclist:
    fieldname = "SFCount"
    check = final_functions.FieldExists(fc, fieldname) # fc goes straight into function
    print check
```

and inside your module I would change the if name...: section to:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('Fire*')
    for fc in fclist:
        fieldname = "SFCount"
        checkfields = FieldExists(fc, fieldname) # fc goes straight into function
        print checkfields
```

Comment: @AndyFisher Glad to help. If you are happy that this solved your issue could you please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 7):

In your main script you have switched a couple of parameters around.  In the first line of your `for` loop you have `fc = fcname` and it should read `fcname = fc`

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/EsriPress/Python/Data/Final/Scratch.gdb"
import final_functions
fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('Fire*')
for fc in fclist:
    fcname = fc
    fieldname = "SFCount"
    check = final_functions.FieldExists(fcname, fieldname)
    print check
```

Changing these around should fix the error.